# default value while adding values inside an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sum up values inside an object, but i am adding a Nullish coalescing operator if undefined or null then it should have zero value. But here instead of getting 10 i am getting 4 only.

```js
let data = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: null
}

console.log(data?.a ?? 0 + data?.b ?? 0 + data?.c ?? 0)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: why you are not doing this with for...in?

Comment: as a example i have put this object as like this, the structure is more of nested and some properties no need to sum up and some properties are not numbers also so specific properties only i need to sum up

Comment: Have you tried putting () around each statement? Like: `(data?.a ?? 0) + (data?.b ?? 0)`?

Comment: @hxhzre posted answer it worked

Answer (score 2):

Just add small brackets this will do. The reason for above not running is because the `??` operator is conditional and will evaluate the first statement since there is value for `data?.a` it will not run the right part of it which is `0 + data?.b ?? 0 + data?.c ?? 0`

```js
let data = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: null
}

console.log((data?.a ?? 0) + (data?.b ?? 0) + (data?.c ?? 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
console.log((data?.a ?? 0) + (data?.b ?? 0) + (data?.c ?? 0))
```

Comment: How about:

let data = {
  a: 4,
  b: 6,
  c: null,
  d: 10,
  e: undefined
}

Answer (score 0):

Ideal case for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

- First: make an array of values with `Object.value`
- Next: reduce (awesome method to master)
- Optional: Use `+` operator for elegant type conversion (might not work in every case)

```
console.log(Object.values(data).reduce(function (sum, value) { return sum + +value }, 0))
```

Good practice is to learn from utility / helper libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/). [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseSum.js) provides nice solution as well